# desing pattern idea for role management

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, design-patterns

I develop a web project. I use Asp.Net MVC, Entity Framework. I will have roles for users in admin panel. Usrs makes processes according to their roles. I want to use design patterns for this projects. Which type of a pattern  do I use for this role authorisation? Any idea?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should probably following the MSDN tutorial on building a role provider (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8fw7xh74(v=vs.100).aspx) or just use the built-in one.

Answer (score 4):

Easiest way to implement role management is using ASP.NET membership provider.

You then have two ways of protecting actions based on roles.

If you want to ensure that only certain roles can execute an action method, you would use the Authorize attribute and define the list of allowed roles:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin, Manager")]
public ActionResult AdministratorsOnly()
{
   return View();
}
```

If you need to hide functionality on the views, you can use the `User.IsInRole()` method to check if the currently logged in user has that role:

```
if(User.IsInRole("Admin"))
{
    <a href="/user/delete">Delete account</a>
}
```